# Cleartext Monit User & Pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, monit

I'm following along with this wonderful book: Reliably Deploying Rails Applications, and there is a suggestion that I:

> Copy the contents of nodes/rails_- postgres_redis.json.example to this
>   file and change the username and password for monit.

The Monit docs say I can it's safe to send a user and pass across with an SSL certificate, but my question is *which* user/pass am I supposed to use? (the one for my VPS? my own computer? some Monit generated user?)

Context: Learning to deploy Rails app to a VPS such as DigitalOcean or Linode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author here, so it's this line:

https://github.com/TalkingQuickly/rails-server-template/blob/master/nodes/rails_postgres_redis.json.example#L27

And it should be a new user name and password just for Monit. So it can be anything you want but ideally shouldn't be the same as any of your other usernames and passwords.